How to create an Auto-Scaling setup in AWS Using CDKTF for ECS Fargate based on SQS Queue Metrics and Shut Down Instances When Demand Decreases?
I'm trying to set up an auto-scaling mechanism in AWS using CDKTF (Cloud Development Kit for Terraform) with TypeScript to provision ECS Fargate services. The scaling should be based on a custom metric that divides the number of messages in an SQS queue by the number of currently running ECS tasks.
Additionally, I need the system to automatically shut down ECS instances when the demand decreases, ensuring there are no running ECS tasks consuming resources unnecessarily when the queue is empty.
What I've Done So Far

ECS Fargate Service: I've defined an ECS Fargate service and attached a target group.
SQS Queue: I've created an SQS queue that receives messages, and I want to use this queue's length as the main metric for scaling.
Auto Scaling Policy: I need to create a custom CloudWatch metric that calculates ApproximateNumberOfMessages divided by the number of running ECS tasks.

What I'm Struggling With

Setting up the CloudWatch metric properly in CDKTF.
Configuring the auto-scaling policy to increase ECS tasks as the number of messages in the SQS queue increases.
Automatically shutting down ECS tasks as the SQS queue is processed and the number of messages decreases, ensuring zero tasks when there are no messages in the queue.

What I Need Help With

How do I correctly set up the custom CloudWatch metric that divides the number of SQS messages by the number of ECS running tasks?
How do I attach this custom metric to an auto-scaling policy using CDKTF in TypeScript?
How do I configure the auto-scaling policy to scale down the ECS tasks, shutting down instances completely when there are no more messages in the SQS queue?

Additional Requirement:

The auto-scaling mechanism should automatically shut down ECS instances to zero when the SQS queue is empty, ensuring that no unnecessary ECS tasks are running when they are not needed.

What I've Tried
I have the following basic CDKTF code structure:
import { App, TerraformStack } from "cdktf";
import { AwsProvider, ecs, sqs, cloudwatch, autoscaling } from "@cdktf/provider-aws";

class MyStack extends TerraformStack {
  constructor(scope: App, name: string) {
    super(scope, name);

    // AWS Provider
    new AwsProvider(this, "AWS", {
      region: "us-east-1",
    });

    // SQS Queue
    const myQueue = new sqs.SqsQueue(this, "MyQueue", {
      name: "my-sqs-queue",
    });

    // ECS Cluster
    const ecsCluster = new ecs.EcsCluster(this, "MyEcsCluster", {
      name: "my-ecs-cluster",
    });

    // ECS Fargate Service
    const ecsService = new ecs.EcsService(this, "MyEcsService", {
      name: "my-ecs-service",
      cluster: ecsCluster.arn,
      launchType: "FARGATE",
      desiredCount: 1,
      taskDefinition: "myTaskDefinition",
    });

    // Custom CloudWatch Metric for Auto Scaling
    const customMetric = new cloudwatch.CloudwatchMetricAlarm(this, "CustomMetricAlarm", {
      alarmName: "MyCustomMetric",
      comparisonOperator: "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
      evaluationPeriods: 2,
      metricName: "MyQueueMessagesPerTask",
      namespace: "AWS/ECS",
      period: 60,
      statistic: "Sum",
      threshold: 10,
    });

    // Auto Scaling Policy for Scale-Out
    const scaleOutPolicy = new autoscaling.AutoscalingPolicy(this, "ScaleOutPolicy", {
      adjustmentType: "ChangeInCapacity",
      scalingAdjustment: 1,
      cooldown: 300,
      estimatedInstanceWarmup: 300,
      metricAggregationType: "Average",
    });

    // Auto Scaling Policy for Scale-In
    const scaleInPolicy = new autoscaling.AutoscalingPolicy(this, "ScaleInPolicy", {
      adjustmentType: "ChangeInCapacity",
      scalingAdjustment: -1,
      cooldown: 300,
      estimatedInstanceWarmup: 300,
      metricAggregationType: "Average",
    });
  }
}

const app = new App();
new MyStack(app, "my-stack");
app.synth();

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!
